# convert single quotes to double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have the following object:

```
{
  name: "TJ",
  age: 14,
  skills: {
    ruby: 14,
    html: 50
  }
}
```

Basically I want to convert that into something like this:

```
{
  "name": "TJ",
  "age": 14,
  "skills": {
    "ruby": 14,
    "html": 50
  }
}
```

So, everything should have double quotes.

I tried to do this:

```
for ( let i in person ) {
   if ( typeof person[i] !== 'object' ) payload[`"${i}"`] = person[i]
   // if object then map inside and to the same
}
```

But it failed because the output is something like this:

```
{
  '"name"': '"TJ"',
  ...
}
```

Also, JSON.stringify is not good because its adding `"{"`.

Does someone have an idea how can I achieve the ones above?

Comment: I dont understand why JSON.stringify is bad

Comment: Keys are by default converted into string. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DDRamone because the object is looking like this http://jsbin.com/vogivanohe/edit?js,console

Comment: @Anderson So that's exactly what you need, dont you?

Comment: If you don't like "\", it's just a way that `jsbin` is rendering. Try the same in chrome console

Comment: @Anderson is the JSON stored in JSON file?

Comment: JSON.stringify() - works, the problem was that I had \n and caused errors

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` perhaps he wants some indentation

Answer (score 5):

You can just use JSON.stringify() right ?

if

```
var a = {
  name: "TJ",
  age: 14,
  skills: {
    ruby: 14,
    html: 50
  }
}

var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```

The thing which you are seeing in the link shared by you(http://jsbin.com/vogivanohe/edit?js,console):
"{\"bool\":true,\"int\":1}"

is just how that console is representing the data. The actual object remains as you expect it to be.

Check the link below:
http://codepen.io/pankaj805/pen/xgXoyQ

Check your browser console.

Comment: @Anderson Please check the link i sent you after the edit

Comment: @Anderson that's what you need im sure. Double check it

Answer (score 0):

Just tried running your code:

```
var person={
  name: "TJ",
  age: 14,
  skills: {
    ruby: 14,
    html: 50
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(person));
```

o/p:

```
{"name":"TJ","age":14,"skills":{"ruby":14,"html":50}}
```

Doesn't add any extra braces...